# Restricting socketIO emission to the closest client by proximity

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-native, socket.io

I am working on a location tracking app using react native, nodejs and socketIO. Clients can emit distress calls from the app, and the other end user (a cop) is able to see the broadcast containing their current location. However, I want to restrict the message to just one of the random cops within a 200metres radius from the client in distress. Right now it emits to even a cop 10,000 miles away.

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking.  On the server, instead of `io.emit()` or `room.emit()` which goes to a large group of connections, you have to find the one user you want to emit to, get their socket and do `socket.emit()` just to them.  How you find that one socket depends upon your internal implementation which you haven't shared any code for us to know what that looks like.